# Excel Macro. Searching between dates. Not working correctly?

Tags: vba, excel

I'll start by stating the goal, then the steps I took, the problem and finally my question.

Goal: 
To search between two dates from jan 2017 till december 2017 in a table

[image: Screenshot of the sheet]

Steps:

- In the red triangled box, nr. 1, I type in the dates, the dates are in EU-format
- In this instance I search between 5 october 2017 and 6 november 2017
- I then press Search, a macro is assigned to it (I'll paste it bellow)

Problem:

- In the red triangled box, nr. 2, you can see what comes up in the search
- In this instance the months may 2017 and june 2017 come up
- The reason, I suspect, is that my search term 5 october 2017, is seen as the 5th month, may, and 6 november, is seen as the 6th month, june

Question:

- How do I get table/macro to show the results between 5 october 2017 and 6 november 2017, instead of the results between May 2017 and June 2017?

Macro used for search button:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Months").ClearAllFilters
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Factuurdatum:"). _
    PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Value, Value2:=ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine found a workaround:

Excel sees the dates in the macro as European dates, but it seems that it uses the American dates in the filter function (that's why Excel converts this).

For the workaround you can write down the dates as: 5/10/2017 or, if you want to use the normal (european) dates, then we can use the macro below:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Months").ClearAllFilters

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Factuurdatum:"). _

    PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("E4").Value, "-", "/"), Value2:= _

    Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value, "-", "/")
```

In this macro the Replace() function is used, this function, in this instance, replaces the ‘-‘ to ‘/’, so it becomes the date we want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following test

```
Sub test()
  Dim startDate As String
  Dim endDate As String

  startDate = Format$(ActiveSheet.Range("E3"), "dd-mmm-yy")
  endDate = Format$(ActiveSheet.Range("F3"), "dd-mmm-yy")

  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Factuurdatum:").PivotFilters
        Do While .count > 0
            .Item(1).Delete
        Loop
        .Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=startDate, Value2:=endDate
    End With

End Sub
```

Reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/19f6838e-1f0f-480f-8cba-682a1c84ce1b/vba-pivot-table-filter-between-two-dates?forum=exceldev

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sadly this didn't work. Luckily a friend of mine found a fix, I just posted the answer.